# Unable to index nested property of dynamic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have this `interface`, which consists of different dynamic keys (API Routes / paths), followed by a method and the response.

```
interface ApiRoutes {
  "auth/login": {
    POST: {
      response: {
        username: string;
        token: string;
      };
    };
  };
  "users/me": {
    GET: {
      response: {
        username: string;
        name: string;
        age: number;
      };
    };
  };
}
```

I'm trying to write a type that will extract a response given the `path` and the `method`. My approach was the following:

```
type ApiResponse<
  Path extends keyof ApiRoutes,
  Method extends keyof ApiRoutes[Path]
> = ApiRoutes[Path][Method]["response"];
```

But the compiler complains, saying that `"response"` can't be used to index

> Type '"response"' cannot be used to index type 'ApiRoutes[Path][Method]'.ts(2536)

Oddly enough, if I ignore the error, VS Code will still show suggestions/autocomplete the response object as if nothing happened.

```
const response: ApiResponse<"auth/login", "POST"> = {
  username: "foo",
  token: "bar",
};
```

**Reference**

- [TypeScript Playground of the issue](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIAdgCUD2BXSAZ2QG8BYAKGWQCI4CALAegBscBzUGgLlMuuoAFAPIBlACq9yVAdSgRC6HCEIQp-WQLyqoIOAFs1yQmCih2Abg2bkYHAGsIIXibMhL1gQF8rM6j40AmRptaEImQx4+P2QAcQBRSWibeUVlVXUY2VDdAyNXc18baj1DF1NCz1k4diMQPH0AI2gizSDZduQgr0pKMABPdBQMbAUlFQgAHg1BODAGZAgAD0gQABNiR36cGDRMXAIFABoNAFkIeZw1xZWnDeQtnb3sfCIAbVn5gF1KAD5kAC8zwO70+DC+b3OlzWEJoqXGqhoX18lAQ6TAyHh6SMIywY2xkzojFYHC4R1oIgkNH+QOk1BypSMNBgOBwNBOMjsjmctEacCgNEoQSAA)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @futur says, this is a backlogged compiler bug at [microsoft/TypeScript#21760](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21760). But I would avoid `//@ts-ignore` except as a last resort.

Instead, my go-to workaround when the compiler loses track of some intended constraint of a generic type is to use [the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to remind it.  Let's say I have some type expression `T` that depends on some as-yet unspecified generic type parameters.  I know that `T` is assignable to `U` but the compiler can't see it for some reason.

Then, instead of writing `T`, I write `Extract<T, U>`.  The compiler will concede that `Extract<T, U>` is assignable to `U` no matter what `T` is.  Later, when the type parameters in `T` are specified, as long as it turns out that I was right about `T` being assignable to `U`, the type `Extract<T, U>` will evaluate to just `T` as desired.  (If I was wrong however, then it will evaluate to `never`, which will probably not be what I wanted... so I should be careful.)

---

In your case you have `ApiRoutes[Path][Method]` and you'd like it to be seen as something with a `response` key.  So it should be assignable to `{response: any}` (or maybe `{response: object}` or `{response: SomeResponseType}`).  If we use `Extract<ApiRoutes[Path][Method], {response: any}>`, now the compiler will let you index into it with `"response"`:

```
type ApiResponse<
    Path extends keyof ApiRoutes,
    Method extends keyof ApiRoutes[Path]
    > = Extract<ApiRoutes[Path][Method], { response: any }>["response"];
```

Now there's no error.  And you can check that it works as expected:

```
type R = ApiResponse<"auth/login", "POST">;
/* type R = {
    username: string;
    token: string;
} */

const response: ApiResponse<"auth/login", "POST"> = {
    username: "foo",
    token: "bar",
};
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgIIAdgCUD2BXSAZ2QG8BYAKGWuQCI4CALAegBscBzUWgLlMpqDkABQDyAZQAqfclSHyoEQuhwhCEGQPnbqedVBBwAthuSEwUUBwDcWnfLA4A1hBB9zlkDbv2Avrbl5fx9gwLo9aEJmE15+MMEAcQBRaTj7GkVlVXVNePTkCINjUw8rAPyhQxN3CzKfCrgOUxA8IwAjaHL80J0emlDfSiGKMABPdBQMbCUVNQgAHh9hODBGZAgAD0gQABNiF1GcGDRMXAIlABofAFkIVZwd9a3XPeQDo5PsfCIAbWXVgC6PgAfMgALzIJJbKCIMDzKZnX7-RgAn63e47AEXUjITKzHLIOAgUbIXzAn60PHZCC0AEBYZjCbILDgz5YGbU+b0JhsTjcbG0MRSWjAgLMABUyEZKBZENkgkKVRKtS8XWojhcbjMKu8FF8yHFzGGCGyYFxHLmfARFvUXIYq15XBAtAFQskItZ8poiuKfFoMBwOBdPg1rj9bTgUGDeusQA)

Comment: Clever solution!

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, this appears to be [a known issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21760), with no clear timeline on resolution.

In essence, TypeScript seems to "forget" that `Method` is `keyof` one of `ApiRoutes`' nested objects. You can see this for yourself if you try adding in a third generic, which I'm calling `Response` in the following example.

```
type ApiResponse<
  Path extends keyof ApiRoutes,
  Method extends keyof ApiRoutes[Path],
  Response extends keyof ApiRoutes[Path][Method] = 'response'
> = ApiRoutes[Path][Method]['response'];
```

This will result in the following error:

```
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'keyof ApiRoutes[Path][string]'.
                                                               ^^^^^^
```

Note that it states `string` for the type of `Method`, indicating that the compiler sees no relation between it and a nested object within `ApiRoutes`.

The only real way to resolve this, for the time being, seems to be to `@ts-expect-error` or `@ts-ignore` the last line of your type declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Credit to @futur answer

One of the [comments](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/21760#issuecomment-364199927) in the issue that @futur has shared is exactly the reason for the cause of the problem.

> The nut of the problem is that the base constraint of `U extends keyof IExample[T]` is a string, even though we would like it to be "bar". This means that `IExample[T][U]` doesn't have a constraint, and therefore can't be indexed by anything except `keyof IExample[T][U]`, which "baz" is not.

In your case,  the constraint `Method extends keyof ApiRoutes[Path]` is a string which means that `ApiRoutes[Path][Method]` doesn't have any constraint.

A simple workaround for your problem would be

```
type ApiResponse<
  Path extends keyof ApiRoutes,
  Method extends keyof ApiRoutes[Path],
  Response extends keyof ApiRoutes[Path][Method] 
> = ApiRoutes[Path][Method][Response];

const response: ApiResponse<"auth/login", "POST", 'response'> = {
  username: "foo",
  token: "bar",
};
```

We also need to constraint the string `response` to `keyof ApiRoute[Path][Methiod]` which is a string literal `response`.